# Right way of getting dates for a current week

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, dayofweek

I have a method that is supposed to put all dates of current week in array.
Here's how it looks like:

```
private void initWeek()
    {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        week_dates = new String[7];

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            week_dates[i] = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i);

        }
    }
```

But when current day is Sunday, it gives dates on the next week, and not on the one that was before Sunday.

Comment: you mean all dates are for 7 days later  ?

Comment: @Javad, Yes, when the current Day is Sunday. But on any other day it's okay.

Comment: You are using troublesome old classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
  week_dates[i] = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
  //calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i);
  calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

Using `Calendar.DATE`, increment 1 day from the Monday that you have assigned in element 0.

I have commented your original code and replaced the line. The original line kept changing initial selected current date.

Comment: It works, but still, not as i want it to. 
I picked Sunday (06/08) on my phone settings and the code gives me this output for days:
https://gist.github.com/Twinkle942910/8f46667a2a506b5b0d4b3bdbd8cfaef5
After Sunday. And what I wanted is all days before this Sunday(Current week).

Comment: Actually, after testing, I realized, that it works fine. Good solution)

Answer (score 1):

this is what i came up with:
edit: try with adding Calendar.DATE

```
private void initWeek()
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    week_dates = new String[7];

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        week_dates[i] = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, gives these dates for each day
https://gist.github.com/Twinkle942910/4e72f11c434f7b825ad8650cb640caaa

Comment: its very interesting , maybe you are changing your calendar somewhere else in your app ? cause its working fine for me

Comment: No, only this method

Comment: Output is the same, after your edit

Comment: check if calendar returns the right date before formatting , also double check if there is something messing with your time settings .

Comment: Seems like everything's okay